# Return html content using @Endpoint springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am able to access http://localhost/manage/welcome page. But not able to get the html. it just returns the string.

```
@Endpoint(id="welcome")
@Component
public class UtilClass {

    @ReadOperation
    public String logger() {
        return "<html><table>sampletable</table></html>";
    }
}
```

Please suggest any way to load html content without using @Controller/ @RestController or thyleaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you don't want to use @Controller

`@ReadOperation` has a parameter to set output content type in spring boot 2.xx.

```java
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.ReadOperation;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Endpoint(id = "welcome")
@Component
public class UtilClass {

    @ReadOperation(produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    public String logger() {
        return "<html>" +
                "<table>" +
                "    <thead><tr>" +
                "       <th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>" +
                "</thead>" +
                " <tbody><tr>" +
                "       <td>1</td><td>Arfat</td></tr>" +
                "</tbody>" +
                "</table>" +
                "</html>";
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to hide the parameters passing in URL